# jquery chosen on disabled option

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I have an select with some option's:

```
 <select id="select">
   <option>1</option>
   <option disabled="true">2</option>
   <option>3</option>
 </select>
```

I'm using Chosen Plugin for jQuery and the problem is that disabled options are removed from the view. But I need to show it as unclickable disabled elements.

Is there any chance with jquery chosen plugin?

--
The example would transformed to:

```
 <ul class="chzn-results">
   <li id="location_select_chzn_o_0" class="active-result result-selected">1</li>
   <li id="location_select_chzn_o_2" class="active-result">3</li>
</ul>
```

So the secound element is not made unvisible, it simply not exist.

Comment: can you inspect the element in Firebug and see if that element has a style of `'display:none;'`, `'visibility:hidden`', or '`opacity:0`'? Or is it completely removed from the DOM?

Comment: Sorry for late answer, I edited the question.

Comment: I took a look at the Source and Docs for the plugin. It's evident that `Chosen automatically highlights selected options and removes disabled options` As mentioned directly in the DOCS. A closer inspection reveals that you'll have a hay-day reconfiguring this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to edit the plugin as outlined here :

http://bitsmash.wordpress.com/2012/10/01/making-disabled-elements-visible-with-the-jquery-chosen-plugin/

The plugin reads in a select, removes it from the DOM, and adds a new ul. Options marked "Disabled" are skipped when adding li to the new ul

Here is the method of interest in chosen.jquery.js

```
AbstractChosen.prototype.result_add_option = function(option) {
  var classes, style;
  if (!option.disabled) {
    option.dom_id = this.container_id + "_o_" + option.array_index;
    classes = option.selected && this.is_multiple ? [] : ["active-result"];
    if (option.selected) classes.push("result-selected");
    if (option.group_array_index != null) classes.push("group-option");
    if (option.classes !== "") classes.push(option.classes);
    style = option.style.cssText !== "" ? " style=\"" + option.style + "\"" : "";
    return '<li id="' + option.dom_id + '" class="' + classes.join(' ') + '"' + style + '>' + option.html + '</li>';
  } else {
    return "";
  }
};
```

Notice that if an option is disabled it returns nothing. Take the line

```
return "";
```

and put in the html/css you would like for a disabled item. Or, you can remove the  if (!option.disabled) block, and add a new  if (!option.disabled) block that adds a special CSS class if the item is disabled.

Next, you need to make sure when users click a disabled item nothing happens. You need to edit this method :

```
 Chosen.prototype.result_select = function(evt) {
  var high, high_id, item, position;
  if (this.result_highlight) {
    high = this.result_highlight;
    high_id = high.attr("id");
    this.result_clear_highlight();
    if (this.is_multiple) {
      this.result_deactivate(high);
    } else {
      this.search_results.find(".result-selected").removeClass("result-selected");
      this.result_single_selected = high;
      this.selected_item.removeClass("chzn-default");
    }
    high.addClass("result-selected");
    position = high_id.substr(high_id.lastIndexOf("_") + 1);
    item = this.results_data[position];
    item.selected = true;
    this.form_field.options[item.options_index].selected = true;
    if (this.is_multiple) {
      this.choice_build(item);
    } else {
      this.selected_item.find("span").first().text(item.text);
      if (this.allow_single_deselect) this.single_deselect_control_build();
    }
    if (!(evt.metaKey && this.is_multiple)) this.results_hide();
    this.search_field.val("");
    if (this.is_multiple || this.form_field_jq.val() !== this.current_value) {
      this.form_field_jq.trigger("change", {
        'selected': this.form_field.options[item.options_index].value
      });
    }
    this.current_value = this.form_field_jq.val();
    return this.search_field_scale();
  }
};
```

Add a block that says, if disabled, return false, then when users click on that item nothing will happen.

Comment: Sorry for late response. Your example works very well, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

nicholmikey's method is correct but here is the code you need to replace in chosen.jquery.js It's just a few simple lines (commented below). Hope this helps.

```
AbstractChosen.prototype.result_add_option = function(option) {
  var classes, style;

    option.dom_id = this.container_id + "_o_" + option.array_index;
    classes = option.selected && this.is_multiple ? [] : ["active-result"];
    if (option.selected) {
      classes.push("result-selected");
    }
    if (option.group_array_index != null) {
      classes.push("group-option");
    }

    // THIS IS NEW ---------------
    if (option.disabled) {
      classes.push("disabled");
    }
    // ---------------------------

    if (option.classes !== "") {
      classes.push(option.classes);
    }
    style = option.style.cssText !== "" ? " style=\"" + option.style + "\"" : "";
    return '<li id="' + option.dom_id + '" class="' + classes.join(' ') + '"' + style + '>' + option.html + '</li>';
};
```

and this

```
Chosen.prototype.result_select = function(evt) {
  var high, high_id, item, position;
  if (this.result_highlight) {
    high = this.result_highlight;
    high_id = high.attr("id");
    this.result_clear_highlight();
    if (this.is_multiple) {
      this.result_deactivate(high);
    } else {
      this.search_results.find(".result-selected").removeClass("result-selected");
      this.result_single_selected = high;
      this.selected_item.removeClass("chzn-default");
    }
    high.addClass("result-selected");
    position = high_id.substr(high_id.lastIndexOf("_") + 1);
    item = this.results_data[position];

    // THIS IS NEW ---------------
    if(this.form_field.options[item.options_index].disabled){
      return false;
    }
    // ---------------------------

    item.selected = true;
    this.form_field.options[item.options_index].selected = true;
    if (this.is_multiple) {
      this.choice_build(item);
    } else {
      this.selected_item.find("span").first().text(item.text);
      if (this.allow_single_deselect) this.single_deselect_control_build();
    }
    if (!(evt.metaKey && this.is_multiple)) this.results_hide();
    this.search_field.val("");
    if (this.is_multiple || this.form_field_jq.val() !== this.current_value) {
      this.form_field_jq.trigger("change", {
        'selected': this.form_field.options[item.options_index].value
      });
    }
    this.current_value = this.form_field_jq.val();
    return this.search_field_scale();
  }
};
```

Finally to grey them out I added this css...

```
.chzn-results .disabled{color:#CCC;}
```

Comment: Work fine for me thanks. But I need a certain time to see that you have deleted the code *'if (!option.disabled) {'* .Perhaps will be better dont delete it and just comment it ;-)